# ошибка http.client.RemoteDisconnected

Tags: python, lxml

*скрипт - парсир работает лишь пару секунд, после перезагрузки компьютера и потом выдает ошибку.* 
*Бан ли это, если ли способы его как-то обойти ? ранее днем скрипт работал отлично*

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\In\Desktop\parser\parser.py", line 46, in <module>
    HTML = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 483, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1268, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1243, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1174, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 282, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 251, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Comment: получаете ли вы похожую ошибку, если выполнить запрос другими средствами, например: `py -mwebbrowser http://example.com/etc` или `http http://example.com/etc` (`py -mpip install httpie`)

Comment: разумеется вместо `http://example.com/...` используйте вашу ссылку.

Comment: *Страница *** не работает*  **`ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Проблема решилась с помощь выполнение следующих команд в консоле*

```
@echo off 

netsh winsock reset 

netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log  


echo You now have to reboot your PC!   

pause
```

Answer (score 2):

> Страница *** не работает ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Эта ошибка означает, что сервер вернул вашему браузеру пустой ответ (даже не пустую веб-страничку, а именно пустой ответ: без статусной строки, http- заголовков и содержимого). Это согласуется с исключением `RemoteDisconnected`, генерируемым в Питоне (на более ранних версиях вы могли `BadStatusLine` исключение в этом случае получить).

Пустой ответ указывает на проблему с сетевым соединением—оно было преждевременно прекращено (не имеет отношения к Питону). Убедитесь, что используете правильный протокол (http, https). Затем можете попробовать по-одному отключать ваш межсетевой экран, антивирус и другое подобное программное обеспечение, относящееся к безопасности. Посмотрите, что сетевые настройки не содержат ничего необычного. Попробуйте также через веб-прокси зайти или наоборот отключить такие вещи как [VPN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN).

Проблема может быть в железе или настройках, начиная от вашего компьютера, продолжая сетевым оборудованием (таким как wifi-маршрутизатором) и заканчивая самим веб-сервером.